# Django: Do I really need apps.py inside an app?

Tags: python, django

When creating an app with `python manage.py startapp myapp`, it automatically creates an `apps.py` file.

```
from django.apps import AppConfig


class MyappConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'myapp'
```

When I removed it, everything seems to work as before (at least my tests all passed). Is it a bad practice to remove these kind of files from the apps? Should we keep them to avoid side effects?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [recommended approach in Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/intro/tutorial02/#activating-models) is to use the app config in your `INSTALLED_APPS`:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'myapp.apps.MyappConfig',
    ...
]
```

If you do this, then the `apps.py` file is required.

However, if you do not customize the app config at all, then it is possible to remove the `apps.py` if you use the app name in `INSTALLED_APPS` instead:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'myapp',
    ...
]
```

Comment: Just found out that this file is also interesting when you need some code to be run at startup: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/applications/#django.apps.AppConfig.ready